# MySQL temporary variable assignment

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a table like the one below.

```
CREATE TABLE People(PeopleId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                    Name VARCHAR(255), 
                    Age INT);

INSERT INTO People(Name,   Age)
            VALUES('Sam',  25),
                  ('John', 24),
                  ('Ria',  14),
                  ('Diya', 23),
                  ('Topel',19),
                  ('Mac',  45);
```

I have created a procedure where I use temporary variable age for some purpose.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Sample;
CREATE PROCEDURE Sample()
BEGIN
  SELECT @Age = Age
    FROM People
   WHERE PeopleId = 4;

   SELECT * 
     FROM People;
END;
```

Don't ask why I am storing age in temporary variable since the above is not the exact procedure.

When I run the procedure, the temporary variable is getting displayed as one of result set along with the result set I get for select query. How can I avoid displaying the temporary variable as part of the result set after assignment?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this one,

```
SET @Age = (SELECT Age FROM People WHERE PeopleId = 16);
```

or

```
SELECT Age INTO @Age
FROM People
WHERE PeopleId = 16;
```